Calculating offset for linestring's coordinates is different to point coordinate
I am trying to calculate geojson's linestring and points offset by using turf.js, but I am not getting correct results.
For example this is the geojson where the point has the same coordinate as linestring's second coordinate:
const testGeojson = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
          {
              "type": "Feature",
              "properties": {},
              "geometry": {
                  "type": "LineString",
                  "coordinates": [
                      [
                          -75.53367810770641,
                          40.09552170656603
                      ],
                      [
                          -75.5335171620643,
                          40.09517701094492
                      ],
                      [
                          -75.53304510887432,
                          40.09558736267683
                      ],
                      [
                          -75.53256765944911,
                          40.09516059682416
                      ],
                      [
                          -75.53192929385972,
                          40.09516470035471
                      ],
                      [
                          -75.53248717711472,
                          40.09473793185126
                      ]
                  ]
              }
          },
          {
              "type": "Feature",
              "properties": {
                  "point_type": "station",
                  "name": "11_18"
              },
              "geometry": {
                  "type": "Point",
                  "coordinates": [
                      -75.5335171620643,
                      40.09517701094492
                  ]
              }
          }
      ],
      "metadata": {
          "XDistance": "10",
          "YDistance": "10",
          "YDirection": "NORTH",
          "XDirection": "EAST",
          "units": "meters"
      }
  };

This is the way how I try to calculate the offset for all features. Here is the codesandbox.
import bearing from '@turf/bearing'
import destination from '@turf/destination'
import distance from '@turf/distance'
import transformTranslate from '@turf/transform-translate'

function getTranslatedGeoJsonFeature({
    feature,
    XDistance,
    XDirection,
    YDistance,
    YDirection,
    units,
  }) {
    const fstPoint =
      feature.geometry.type === 'LineString' ? feature.geometry.coordinates[0] : feature.geometry.coordinates
    const options = { units }
    
    // const bearing = 270 // west
    // const bearing = 90 // east
    const XDestination = destination(fstPoint, XDistance, XDirection === 'WEST' ? 270 : 90, options)
    
    const XDestinationCoordinates = XDestination.geometry.coordinates
    // const bearing = 0 // north
    // const bearing = 180 // south
    const YDestination = destination(XDestinationCoordinates, YDistance, YDirection === 'NORTH' ? 0 : 180, options)
    const YDestinationCoordinates = YDestination.geometry.coordinates
    
    const offsetDistance = distance(fstPoint, YDestinationCoordinates, options)
    const offsetBearing = bearing(fstPoint, YDestinationCoordinates)
    
    return transformTranslate(feature, offsetDistance, offsetBearing, options)
    return null
  }

  const offsetMetadata = testGeojson.metadata
  const XDistance = parseFloat(offsetMetadata.XDistance)
  const YDistance = parseFloat(offsetMetadata.YDistance)
  
  const translatedFeatures = testGeojson.features.map((feature) => {
    const translatedGeojson = getTranslatedGeoJsonFeature({
      feature,
      XDistance,
      YDistance,
      XDirection: offsetMetadata.XDirection === 'WEST' ? 'EAST' : 'WEST',
      YDirection: offsetMetadata.YDirection === 'NORTH' ? 'SOUTH' : 'NORTH',
      units: offsetMetadata.units,
    })
    return translatedGeojson
  })
  
  console.log({translatedFeatures})

The result of translatedFeatures is:
[
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    -75.53379567034386,
                    40.09543177452967
                ],
                [
                    -75.53363472410626,
                    40.09508707890856
                ],
                [
                    -75.53316267162518,
                    40.09549743064047
                ],
                [
                    -75.53268522146277,
                    40.0950706647878
                ],
                [
                    -75.53204685588042,
                    40.095074768318355
                ],
                [
                    -75.53260473839816,
                    40.0946479998149
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "point_type": "station",
            "name": "11_18"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -75.53363472410626,
                40.09508707890857
            ]
        }
    }
]

The point's coordinate doesn't match with linestring's second coordinate.

please see the discussion at https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/479988/79 which explains that down to the atomic level you coordinates do match.
